# How do I resolve this circular reference initialization error?

Tags: swift, initialization, circular-reference

I have a class `Question` with a nested struct `MultipleChoiceAnswers`. When initializing `Question`, I initialize `MultipleChoiceAnswers` as well, giving it a reference to the `Question` instance. I then want to assign the `MultipleChoiceAnswers` instance to the property `answers` of the `Question` instance.

Here's an overview:

```
struct Answer {
  let value:Double;
  let isCorrect:Bool;
}

class Question {
  struct MultipleChoiceAnswers {
    let question:Question;
    let answers:[Answer];
  }

  let answers:MultipleChoiceAnswers;

  init( possibleAnswersCount:UInt ) {
    let answers:[Answer];
    /*
      here I generate some Answer instances
      that get appended to the answers Array
    */
    self.answers = MultipleChoiceAnswers( question: self, answers: answers ); // <-- error
  }
}
```

However, this results in the error:

> Variable 'self.answers' used before being initalized

This makes sense. Can I resolve this error somehow, though? I was thinking of resolving this with `weak` or `unowned` (preferably the latter, since it should be a <strike>strong</strike> guaranteed non-`nil` reference), but I don't think I completely understand the logic yet, because changing `MultipleChoiceAnswers` to:

```
struct MultipleChoiceAnswers {
  unowned let question:Question;
  let answers:[Answer];
}
```

... does not resolve the error.

How can I resolve this error, while keeping a <strike>strong</strike> guaranteed non-`nil` circular reference?

<sup>P.S.: to be honest, I'm not even entirely sure yet whether I actually *need* this circular reference to begin with, but since this tentative implementation raised this error, I got curious about a possible resolution anyway.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `!` here:

```
let answers:MultipleChoiceAnswers!
```

`answers` needs to have a value prior to passing `self` to another function. By declaring `answers` to be an implicit unwrapped optional, you give it the default value of `nil`. That meets the requirement, and off you go. Since you do give it a value before `init` finishes, you'll never have trouble with accidentally unwrapping a `nil`. (But of course you should always be careful with `!`.)

This is discussed in ["Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_99) in the Swift Programming Guide.

Comment: This works, indeed. Thank you. So, (going by the downvote I got for this question) does this mean that `weak` and/or `unowned` were completely irrelevant to my case? Are those merely used to prevent memory leaks, perhaps?

Comment: unowned was a good choice here. I have no idea why you were downvoated.